# busboy fileSize limit event is not being called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, limit, busboy

I'm uploading a file using express into a MongoDb. All is working fine, but now I'm trying to set a size limit.
Setting `busboy` configuration as  [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) site declares:

```
 var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers,  limit: { files: 1, fileSize: 50000 }  });
```

then:

```
file.on('limit', function(data) {                                               
     console.log("LIMIT");
});
```

By the way, I can try to find a workaround by stopping everything when the data chucks add up to the limit size.

```
file.on('data', function(data) {                                          
   fileSize+=data.length;
    if (fileSize>50000){
        //limit reached 
   }                         
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limit config option is `limits` and not `limit`. Change that and it should work.

Comment: Indeed, that's it.- Thanks